# Add items before recyclerview

Tags: android, image, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I have an activity with a recycler view. But I need to add an image before recycler view (like instagram stories before feed). **How do I implement it?**

my xml file

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            app:title="Locations"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/white" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cropmap"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_marker" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cropmap"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="168dp"
        android:background="@drawable/cropmap" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/main_progress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The perfect way of doing this is to take advantage of "Item View type" in recyclerview. Basically what you should be doing is populating the image on top inside the recyclerview itself. The image will appear as the first item in recyclerview and other items will come subsequently. This can be implemented by using ItemViewType in recyclerview. 
Some useful resources can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26245463/6414086) and [here](https://www.journaldev.com/12372/android-recyclerview-example)

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of the full potential of fragments. You can set a `FrameLayout` between your top bar and recyclerView, and then add a fragment there, or just simply use the `<fragment>` tag on your xml. For more info about flexible UI, please take a look in the Android documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui).

Think of this fragment as your other section, like the Instagram example you just gave. There you can add what you want (ViewPager, HorizontalScrollView, etc), and be reflected when you inject the fragment in your layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cropmap"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/cropmap"
        android:layout_weight="3"  />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_marker"
        android:layout_weight="7" />

 </Linearayout>


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/main_progress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: You could at least try to share some knowledge, instead of giving a solution straight away, without any explanation...

Comment: No, now image in the end of screen and when i scrolling image isn`t hiding

Comment: Can u post the full code of xml file including root layout also.